# Formatting XML in SSRS report

Tags: xml, reporting-services, format, sqlreportingservice

OK, New to SSRS and newer still to XML, anyway Is way a previous posting that showed adding code at report level the referencing this code with a text box. I tried the example and it only displays as error. I am using the "FOR XML AUTO ELEMENTS" within my query to generate the XML. I tried a previous post example using code at the report level but I get an error within the textbox on referencing the code..

The query works outside of SSRS and within SSRS, but within SSRS it just does not format which my users need.

Any help or pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Query runs just cannot get it to format within the SSRS report.

Comment: so what exactly is the problem you are having? All I gather is you have an issue!

Comment: You need to add much more info, what is the query? what errors do you get? what do you expect to see in SSRS, what do you mean by "Format"? Show examples, of what you have tried and what you are trying to achieve.